# Salesforce Experience Cloud "Included" CDN

Tags: digital-experience, cdn

Is there a post and/or documentation showing how much enabling "Included" CDN for Digital Experience would boost end-user performance?

It is widely accepted that CDN should improve performance, and Salesforce as of 11-Aug-2023 partners with Akamai which is well known, but I have not seen figures that could back it up (for now only a dozen of [high-level articles](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2023/03/enable-cdn-to-load-lightning-experience-faster), which are great for non-techies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance boosts from a CDN are widely variable, location specific, and implementation specific. The reason detailed numbers are hard to find is that they are hard to gather and of limited value outside the scenarios used to run the test.

A user based in the same city as the server will see a much smaller boost than someone far away. Put an ocean in the middle and the boost is even bigger. I've even encountered edge cases in non-Salesforce contexts where a CDN *slowed* the load times because the CDN was further away from the user than the server itself (came up in a context of an organization who had their servers up the street from their office and on the same provider's backbone, and moved to a CDN whose nearest location was across town and on a different backbone – their main audience was across the country from the office and they were claiming page load times that defied physics for the main audience). After you deal with geography you have to account for payload size, file count, cache-ability, and other details that go into a page's load time.

Any published numbers would be mostly irrelevant to your use case unless by chance your server and audience locations overlapped the tester. Arguably Salesforce has enough pockets of overlap that someone could have developed ball-park numbers of interest – but the Hyperforce switch is also going to increase the complexity of existing measures.

Comment: I see your point; it makes sense. I wonder if a model is ever documented to help, but perhaps this is one of the cases that we must test case-by-case anyway.